# Overlapping divs and keeping responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of an issue here. I'm trying to get this page so that on desktop it has an alternating flow of Images with a card of text offset and overlaid which is working fine in this first example [image]

So it would start there and the next image would be on the right with the overlaid card on the left, and keep alternating. ON desktop the idea is that they flow that way with the same amount of space between card/image sections regardless of whether the card is shorter or longer (more text)

Right now when I shrink the page down all the way to mobile size, I have the general layout that I want except I also have an issue there where card sections are overlapping on top of the next card section.

How can I fix the offset/gap issues on desktop but have it also give an equal amount of space for mobile?

Pen here:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVdNXL

```css
.callToActionText{
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2.25;
    color: rgb(156, 164, 177);
}

.jWuUNX {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.bg-white {
    background: #fff;
}

.hide-overflow-x {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


article{
  display:block;
}

main{
  display:block;
}

.lvZRD {
    min-height: 50vh;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    margin-bottom:200px;
}

.eNpugc {
    max-width: 1440px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}

.fuYpln {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.chuVCt {
    max-height: 480px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.cdhhEw {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%);
    right: 50%;
    filter: drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 0px 10px);
}

.kJGXut {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: initial;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fuzbkA {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 60;
    padding: 0px 30px;
}

.ckwpzP {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 0px 12px 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.izjVlt {
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman';
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(69, 77, 84);
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.jpddbB {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2.25;
    color: rgb(97, 104, 113);
}

.kNTftn {
    padding-bottom: 85px;
    position: relative;
}
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.jruQOv {
    margin-top: 92px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.2;
    color: rgb(167, 175, 188);
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
  box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

.ktrBmY {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dJDUPg {
    text-align: center;
}


.bHgSIS {
    max-width: 164px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

.hlypoQ {
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: initial;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.bTZMxL {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.erLuwx {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: rgb(97, 104, 113);
}


.hDOnrl {
    min-height: 50vh;
    padding: 80px 0px;
}

.fqUDXq {
    max-width: 1440px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}

.htSAJx {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cwCFzv {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 0px 12px 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.jULdGM {
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman';
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(69, 77, 84);
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.lciScj {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2.25;
    color: rgb(97, 104, 113);
}

.wxuto {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 60;
    padding: 0px 30px;
}


@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1300px){
.cwCFzv {
    padding: 45px 55px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}

}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
}





/**********************/





@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
}
@media (min-width:1300px){
  .ckwpzP {
    padding: 45px 55px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.ckwpzP {
    padding: 40px;
}
}

@media (min-width:992px){
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
  .ckwpzP {
    padding: 40px 50px 35px;
}
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
}

.hDOnrl2 {
    min-height: 50vh;
   
}

.htSAJx.col-md-12 {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.htSAJx {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jTBujm {
    max-height: initial;
    cursor: initial;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.jTBujm img {
    width: 100%;
}

.fqUDXq {
    max-width: 1440px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}

.wxuto {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 60;
    padding: 0px 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
.col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}
}

.cwCFzv {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 0px 12px 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

@media (min-width: 1300px){
.cwCFzv {
    padding: 45px 55px;
}

.jULdGM {
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman';
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(69, 77, 84);
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.lciScj {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2.25;
    color: rgb(97, 104, 113);
}
}

.dmbg {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.jULdGM {
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman';
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(69, 77, 84);
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    padding-top:30px;
}

.dmBg-vertical {
    padding: 20px 0 60px;
}


@media (min-width: 992px){
.tfs-slider .background-image{
    background-position: 0 0 !important;
}

.col-md-11 {
    width: 100%;
}
}

.dmBg-vertical .col-xs-12 {
    padding: 0 35px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.separator-big-small {
    border-right: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
}

.cXmEBU {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(69, 77, 84);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.lciScj {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2.25;
    color: rgb(97, 104, 113);
}

.iACmBG {
    max-width: 540px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.dmBg-vertical .col-xs-12 {
    padding: 0 35px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.cXmEBU {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(69, 77, 84);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}

/***Mobile stylings***/

@media (max-width: 700px){


.hDOnrl{
    margin-bottom:300px;
}

.lvZRD{
    margin-bottom:300px;
}

.hDOnrl2{
    margin-bottom:400px;
}

.wxuto{
    transform:translate3d(40px,-49.2139,0px) !important;
}

.pbcColOne{
    padding:65px;
}

}
```

```html
<!-- wp:html -->
<div class="sc-brqgnP lvZRD" style="margin-bottom: 400px;">
<div style="margin: 0; display: block;">
<div style="margin: 0; display: block;">
<div class="sc-EHOje eNpugc row">
<div class="sc-jAaTju fuYpln col-md-8 col-md-offset-0">
<div class="sc-jDwBTQ chuVCt">
<div class="sc-cMljjf cdhhEw sc-bZQynM kJGXut"></div>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250x850" />

</div>
</div>
<div class="sc-gPEVay fuzbkA col-md-5 col-md-offset-7" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -83.6149px, 0px);">
<div class="sc-iRbamj ckwpzP">
<div class="sc-bwzfXH izjVlt">About Us</div>
<span style="font-weight: 400;">We are building a first of a kind network of doctors who offer Direct Primary Care and Anti-Aging (Cosmetic Dermatology) medical memberships for patients who want optimum healthcare driven by the latest in technology and -- we offer a concierge service (management and patient referral service) for doctors that specializes in converting "insurance" practices to the "membership" model.</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /wp:html -->

<!-- wp:html -->
<div class="sc-cvbbAY hDOnrl">
<div>
<div class="sc-ifAKCX fqUDXq row">
<div class="sc-brqgnP htSAJx col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="sc-cMljjf ktDtlN"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250x850" /></div>
</div>
<div class="sc-jAaTju wxuto col-md-5 col-md-offset-0" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -49.2139px, 0px);">
<div class="sc-jDwBTQ cwCFzv">
<div class="sc-bdVaJa jULdGM">Our Mission</div>
<span class="sc-bwzfXH lciScj">Our mission is twofold:
1) To free doctors from the “fee for service” practice model that has placed increasing demands on doctors requiring high volume of patients and exhaustive documentation with a medical membership model that allows doctors to do what they do best -- practice medicine
2) To offer patients Direct Primary Care medical memberships that include genetic testing to identify health risks, create patients health baseline and build a preventative health care plan for patients to monitor their progress on our mobile app and Anti-Aging memberships that offer preferential services and discounted procedures for a monthly fee.</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- wp:html -->
<div class="sc-brqgnP lvZRD" style="margin-bottom: 400px;">
<div style="margin: 0; display: block;">
<div style="margin: 0; display: block;">
<div class="sc-EHOje eNpugc row">
<div class="sc-jAaTju fuYpln col-md-8 col-md-offset-0">
<div class="sc-jDwBTQ chuVCt">
<div class="sc-cMljjf cdhhEw sc-bZQynM kJGXut"></div>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250x850" />

</div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="sc-gPEVay fuzbkA col-md-5 col-md-offset-7" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -63.6149px, 0px);">
<div class="sc-iRbamj ckwpzP">
<div></div>
<div class="sc-bwzfXH izjVlt">Patient Benefits</div>
<span class="sc-htpNat jpddbB">Medical Memberships for Direct Primary Care and Anti-Aging (Cosmetic Dermatology) provide patients with personalized, accessible care on an unlimited basis. Membership doctors have only hundreds of patients at any given time, compared to the thousands that traditional doctors see that leads to better service from your physician and improved health for the patient. Visit our "Patients" page for a list of benefits.</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /wp:html -->

<!-- wp:html -->
<div class="sc-cvbbAY hDOnrl">
<div>
<div class="sc-ifAKCX fqUDXq row">
<div class="sc-brqgnP htSAJx col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="sc-cMljjf ktDtlN"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250x850" /></div>
</div>
<div class="sc-jAaTju wxuto col-md-5 col-md-offset-0" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -49.2139px, 0px);">
<div class="sc-jDwBTQ cwCFzv">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="sc-bdVaJa jULdGM">Doctor Benefits</div>
<span class="sc-bwzfXH lciScj">Physician practices described as “membership medicine” for Direct Primary Care have been springing up across the country during the past decade and expanding to Anti-Aging (Cosmetic Dermatology). These practices, in which patients pay a monthly or annual retainer to their doctor or medical office for a contracted bundle of services, offer an alternative model for physicians who hope to spend less time on paperwork and more time with patients. Visit our "Doctors" page for a list of benefits.</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- wp:html -->
<div class="sc-brqgnP lvZRD" style="margin-bottom: 400px;">
<div style="margin: 0; display: block;">
<div style="margin: 0; display: block;">
<div class="sc-EHOje eNpugc row">
<div class="sc-jAaTju fuYpln col-md-8 col-md-offset-0">
<div class="sc-jDwBTQ chuVCt">
<div class="sc-cMljjf cdhhEw sc-bZQynM kJGXut"></div>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250x850" />

</div>
</div>
<div class="sc-gPEVay fuzbkA col-md-5 col-md-offset-7" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -63.6149px, 0px);">
<div class="sc-iRbamj ckwpzP">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="sc-bwzfXH izjVlt">Employer Benefits</div>
<span class="sc-htpNat jpddbB">Medical memberships combined with wrap around health insurance policies have proven to generate healthier employees, improve attendance, increase benefits offerings and overall cost savings per employee. The health insurance industry continues to change and cost of employee coverage increases, many businesses are finding it harder than ever to cover employees without taking a serious hit to their finances. Traditional health insurance for employees can be one of the largest costs incurred throughout the fiscal year. Our in-house insurance broker can offer customized group health ACA conforming health insurance plans for any size and type of business to improve your employees health and save money. Visit our "Employer" page for a list of benefits.
</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /wp:html -->
```

Answer (score 0):

That issues comes from your in-line style of transform:

```
style="transform: translate3d(0px, -83.6149px, 0px);"
```

So you'll need to remove that when the screen size changes. Remove that and it won't overlap the picture.

Comment: I want it to overlap the picture though. I just don't want each parent div overlapping the next. So each image should have the text box overlapping but there should be space before the next div of image and text card

Comment: so the first image and text in my example is what I want for each main div. I just don't want the text card to overlap the top of the next image